# fscanf doesn't read the first char of first word (in c)

Tags: c, linux, file, loops

I'm using fscanf function in a c code to read a file contains 1 line of words separated by white spaces, but for example if the first word is 1234, then when I print it the output is 234, however the other words in the file are read correctly, any ideas?

```
FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");

char arr = getc(file);

char temp[20];  

while(fscanf(file,"%s",temp)!= EOF && i<= column)
{
 printf("word %d: %s\n",i, temp);
}
```

Comment: OK, I give up, what is the getc call for, if not to read a char?

Comment: @MartinJames I thought It will read the whole file and put it in array of chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the posted code, with my comments

```
When asking a question about a run time problem, 
post code that cleanly compiles, and demonstrates the problem

FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");
// missing check of `file` to assure the fopen() was successful

char arr = getc(file);
// this consumed the first byte of the file, (answers your question)

char temp[20];  

while(fscanf(file,"%s",temp)!= EOF && i<= column)
// missing length modifier. format should be: "%19s"
// 19 because fscanf() automatically appends a NUL byte to the input
// 19 because otherwise the input buffer could be overrun,
//    resulting in undefined behaviour and possible seg fault event
// should be checking (also) for returned value == 1 
// this will fail as soon as an `white space` is encountered
// as the following call to fscanf() will not read/consume the white space
// suggest a leading space in the format string to consume white space
{
    printf("word %d: %s\n",i, temp);
    // the variable 'i' is neither declared nor modified
    //    within the scope of the posted code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

char arr = getc(file);

Probably above line is causing to loose the first char.

Comment: I removed this code because I realized that I don't actually need it.

Comment: if it solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: I cannot accept an answer within the first 10 minutes of posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
char arr = getc(file);
```

reads the first character from the file stream and iterates the file stream *file*

Comment: how is a single call to getc() going too iterate the file?

Comment: @user3629249 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/ : The internal file position indicator is then advanced to the next character.

Comment: the question is about 'c' not 'c++'

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rewind(file)` after `char arr = getc(file)` to reset your file stream to the beginning.

Other example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE    *f;
    FILE    *r;
    char    str[100];
    size_t  buf;

    memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
    r = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    f = fopen("out.txt", "w+b");
    fscanf(r, "%s", str);
    rewind(r); // without this, the first char won't be written
    buf = fread(str, sizeof(str), 1, r);
    fwrite(str, sizeof(str), 1, f);
    fclose(r);
    fclose(f);

    return (0);
}
```